# Linux Memory Allocation/De-allocation

Tags: linux, memory

will the `pgfree/s` command happen without `pgscand/s`?  How and
what is the difference between `pgfree/s` and  `pgscank/s`?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the StackExchange @Ajay Ponugoti

`$ man sar`

```
-B     Report paging statistics.  The following values are displayed:
```

pgpgin/s
                 Total number of kilobytes the system paged in from disk per second.

          pgpgout/s
                 Total number of kilobytes the system paged out to disk per second.

          fault/s
                 Number of page faults (major + minor) made by the system per second.
                 This is not a count of page faults that generate I/O, because some page 
                 faults can be resolved without I/O.

          majflt/s
                 Number of major faults the system has made per second, those which have 
                 required loading a memory page from disk.

          pgfree/s
                 Number of pages placed on the free list by the system per second.

          pgscank/s
                 Number of pages scanned by the kswapd daemon per second.

          pgscand/s
                 Number of pages scanned directly per second.

Comment: What is the difference between "system per second and "kswapd daemon per second"?
My doubt is both are system kernel related tasks but what is the reason behind we have 2

Answer (score 0):

There are different "system per/sec"

There is:

**System\File Read Operations/sec**:  is the combined rate of file system read requests to all devices on the computer, including requests to read from the file system cache.

**System\File Write Operations/sec** is the combined rate of the file system write requests to all devices on the computer,

**System\System Up Time** is the elapsed time (in seconds) that the computer has been running since it was last started.

**System\System Calls/sec** is the combined rate of calls to operating system service routines by all processes running on the computer.

The **kswapd daemon** scans for available pages for the free list if the number of pages on the list becomes too low. This daemon only runs when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable info.
One last question - then what is Number of pages scanned directly per second? with respect to kswapd ?